When to use \set{} or \{\}
When should I use \set{...} or \{...\}?
In obvious case like when defining a set that is no question of course.
But what for something like this: \min\set{x,y} vs. \min\{x,y\}?
If I need surrounding curly braces should I always use set? Or only for sets and otherwise \{?

And where is \set defined?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

\{ is a standard latex command \set is not defined by latex or by standard packages such as amsmath, it may be defined to produce the same output or it may not, you have not shown the definition.

Note: MathJax specific questions are off-topic.

Okay, my mistake. I thought \set was standard LaTeX.
It turns out I was using MathJax which auto-imports many packages.
The \set command comes from the braket library.
Because of this I will probably stick to \{...\}

Minimum example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}
\(\set{x}\)
\end{document}


Is this an answer to the question or a try to make the question clearer? If the last you should add it to the question. Answers should only be used to answer a question but not to add additional information to the question.

This is an answer. I will stick to {}.
I cannot mark it as an answer though yet.

Note that MathJax is not LaTeX, although the syntax is very similar. The underlying mechanism how things are typeset are very different. Because of this, MathJax questions (along with relevant answers) are typically off-topic on this site.
